# Using Corona how can I get my app to register multiple button presses when the user performs a single drag gesture?

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I am generating a 6x6 grid of buttons using widget.newButton. I would like the user to be able to add numbers to a selection by touching the screen and then dragging their finger over the desired buttons. For example if I wanted to select "811030" (i.e the top row of the grid) then I would just drag my finger over it.

[image]
Here is the code I have so far:

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

local function handleButtonEvent( event )
local phase = event.phase

if "moved" == phase then
    print("Button Pressed")
end
end

function tileRow(numTiles, padding)

local tileWidth = (display.contentWidth / numTiles) - padding
local x = padding/2
local y = display.contentHeight - numTiles * (tileWidth + padding)

    for i = 1, numTiles, 1 do
        for j = 1, numTiles, 1 do 
            local myButton = widget.newButton
            {
                left = x,
                top = y,
                width = tileWidth,
                height = tileWidth,
                id = "button_"..i..j,
                label = math.random(0,9),
                onEvent = handleButtonEvent,
            }
            x = x + tileWidth + padding
        end
        x = padding/2
        y = y + tileWidth + padding
    end
end

tileRow(6,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access the label inside the event handler, and build your full number from there.
I'll let you handle the corner cases, like putting fullNumber back to "" at one point :)

```
local fullNumber = ""
local function handleButtonEvent( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    local btn = event.target
    local btnLabel = btn.label

    if "moved" == phase then
        print("Button Pressed with label:"..btnLabel)
        fullNumber=fullNumber..btnLabel
        print("Full number: "..fullNumber)
    end
end
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

- Get the button under the finger

In handleButtonEvent, you can retrieve the coordinates (x, y) where the user is touching and moving his finger. Indeed the event.target is not enough to your purpose because the event.target will always be equal to the first touched button.
You have to implement this function GetMyButton(x, y) that will return a widget.newButton. It should not be hard.

- Get the label of the found button

According to [widget_button.lua](https://github.com/coronalabs/framework-widgets/blob/master/widgetLibrary/widget_button.lua), to get the label of a button you should do :

```
local btnLabel = btn:getLabel()
```

- Concatenate the found labels (be aware of duplication)